# Show that the smallest prime factor of $47^n - 14$ is less than $15$ for $n$ a positive integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that the smallest prime factor of $47^n - 14$ is less than $15$ for $n$ a positive integer.

I have not seen problems where we are to approximate the smallest prime factor of an integer. I think that there is a theorem saying that the smallest prime factor of $n$ is less than $\sqrt n$, but I don't think that this is what is wanted here.

Is there an alternative approach using some elementary methods from number theory that would be applicable here?

Comment: You could probably show something like: for some numbers, $47^n-14$ is divisible by $2$, for others, it's divisible by $3$, ..., for others, it's divisible by $13$, and together, those make up all the natural numbers.

Comment: It's clearly divisible by $3$ for all odd $n$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla, it is impossible that $47^n-14$ is divisible by $2$ because it is an odd number.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  An obvious first step is to compute your sequence modulo $3,5,11,13$.

Comment: It’s clearly divisible by $5$ for any $n=2(2k-1)$ where $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: It’s clearly divisible by $13$ for any $n=4k$ where $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Angelo Which finishes the proof : you proved that for $n=4k$ and $n=4k-2$ the proposition holds (which is all even numbers), and the second comment above shows that for all odd $n$ things work out.

Comment: By the way, the smallest prime factor of $n$ is less than [or equal to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102755/requireenclose-enclosehorizontalstrike-rm-greatest-least-prime-factor) $\sqrt n$

Comment: This is called a "cover" , many such sequences can be shown to produce never a prime number.

Comment: @Angelo Ah yeah that's true. But the same idea still applies (which I guess you applied in the comments!)

Comment: @Piquito $4$ is not an odd number.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand your reply. Why cannot the positive integer $n$ be  even?

Comment: The user you mentioned claimed the divisibility by $3$ only for odd numbers $n$. For even , we can establish other divisibilities.

Comment: @Peter Thanks you very much. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove $47^n-14\equiv0\pmod p$ for $p\in\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$ and we clearly can discard $2$ and $7$ so the prime $p\in\{3,5,11,13\}$.

First $47$ is equal to $2,5,3,8$ modulo $3,5,11,13$ respectively and similarly  $14$ is equal to $2,4,3,1$ modulo the same primes respectively.

►Case $p=13$.$$47^n-14\equiv0\pmod{13}\iff8^n-1\equiv0\pmod{13}$$ The order of $8$ modulo $13$ is $4$ so we get $n\equiv0\pmod4$. This means that $47^{4n}-14$ is always divisible by $13$.

►Case $p=11$  $$47^n-14\equiv0\pmod{11}\iff3^n-3\equiv0\pmod{11}\iff3^{n-1}-1=0\pmod{11}$$ the order of $3$ modulo $11$ is $5$ so for $n\equiv1\pmod{5}$ we have the divisor $11$.

►Case $p=5$  $$47^n-14\equiv0\pmod{5}\iff2^n-4\equiv0\pmod{5}\iff2^{n-2}-1=0\pmod{5}$$
Since the order of $2$ modulo $5$ is $4$, we need $n\equiv2\pmod4$ to have divisor $5$.

►Case $p=3$

Similarly we get $n-1$ is even so $n$ is odd.

We have shown that the statement is true for
$$n\equiv0\pmod4\\n\equiv2\pmod4\\n\text{ odd }$$
For $n\equiv1\pmod5\iff n=5k+1$, if $k$ is even then $n$ is odd so the statement is true.

Looking at when $k$ is odd so we have $n=5(2k+1)+1=10k+6$. It follows that if $k$ is even then $n=20k+6\equiv2\pmod4$ and if $k$ is odd then $n=20k+16\equiv0\pmod4$.

Thus we have prove the statement for all $n$.

Comment: Piquito, do not write anything in Spanish. Please, translate “ el orden de $3$ “ to English.

Comment: Piquito, $n=5x+1$ and $n=4y+3$ do not imply $4y-5x=2$, indeed $4y-5x=n-3-(n-1)=-2$.

Comment: Piquito, could you explain better why, since the equation $4y-5x=-2$ always has solutions, we cover all the exponents modulo $4$ ?

Comment: @Angelo Look at my edition please. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: @Angelo  Note that the three first proven cases involve all the exponents so for the exponents $5n+1$ we have proven that all the factors $3,5,11,13$ appear including $11$.

Comment: Piquito, the three first proven cases ($p=13$, $p=11$, $p=5$) do not involve all the exponents indeed they involve all the even exponents but not all the odd exponents. In fact the odd exponents involved are : $1$, $11$, $21$, $31$, …, which are not all the odd exponents. In order to complete the proof you need the fourth case, that is, $p=3$, which involves all the odd exponents, none excluded.

Comment: What remains being $n=10k+6$ the case of $k$ odd an even has been proven before. The last used $k$ is not this of the assumed $k$ odd. If you want to see more clearly put  $n=10m+6$. The first small values can be verified

Comment: Piquito, the three first proven cases ($p=13$, $p=11$, $p=5$) do not involve the following odd exponents: $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$, $13$, $15$, $17$, $19$, $23$, etc.